# WCF Json Service not configured correctly

Tags: wcf, json.net

Using .Net 3.5. Trying to provide a WCF - Json service.
Looked for implementation examples and after failing with a few went with Code Project "How to create a JSON WCF RESTful Service in 60 seconds"

This is my App.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfJsonRestService.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="WcfJsonRestService.Service1Behavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress = "http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfJsonRestService/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
        <endpoint address ="http://localhost:8732/service1" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfJsonRestService.IService1">
          <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <!-- Metadata Endpoints -->
        <!-- The Metadata Exchange endpoint is used by the service to describe itself to clients. --> 
        <!-- This endpoint does not use a secure binding and should be secured or removed before deployment -->
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WcfJsonRestService.Service1Behavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WcfJsonRestService.Service1Behavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

In my browser I run:

```
`http://localhost:8732/Service1/data/10`
```

And I get

```
        <Fault xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/envelope/none">
<Code>
<Value>Sender</Value>
<Subcode>
<Value xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">a:DestinationUnreachable</Value>
</Subcode>
</Code>
<Reason>
<Text xml:lang="en-GB">
The message with To 'http://localhost:8732/Service1/data/10' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. Check that the sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree.
</Text>
</Reason>
</Fault>
```

Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

try to add this

```
[ServiceBehavior(AddressFilterMode=AddressFilterMode.Any)]
```